# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>

Tags: json, list, spring-boot, dictionary, serialization

Obviously I have a deserialization problem.
I want to insert a list of new products in the db.
At first I had this problem:

```
"trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type 
    `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.resources.entities.Product>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`);
```

So i created a wrapper "ProductWrapper"

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductWrapper implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    List<Product> products;   
}
```

the first problem is solved but I have another problem that I can not solve. I use a map inside the list.

```
 "timestamp": "2022-11-14T10:45:18.453+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 7, column: 27] (through reference chain: com.example.resources.dto.ProductWrapperDTO[\"products\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.resources.entities.Product[\"dimensions\"])\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:391)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:185)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:160)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:133)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)})
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String productCode;
    private String name;
    private float pricePerUnit;
    @Type(type="jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, Double> dimensions = new HashMap<>(); 
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {

    private ProductService productService;
    
    @PostMapping
    public void addProducts(@Valid @RequestBody ProductWrapper products) {
        productService.addProducts(products.getProducts());
    }
}
```

```
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public void addProducts(List<Product> products) {
        for (Product product : products) {
            productRepository.save(product);
        }   
    }
}
```

This is my request body, post in postman:

```
{
   "products": [
        {
            "productCode": "P100",
            "name": "produit 1",
            "pricePerUnit": "250.99",
            "dimensions": [
                {
                    "productHeight": "55",
                    "productWeight": "20"
                }
            ]
        },
         {
            "productCode": "P101",
            "name": "produit 2",
            "pricePerUnit": "250.99",
            "dimensions": [
                {
                    "productHeight": "60",
                    "productWeight": "15"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the issue because `dimensions` cannot be deserialized to a map. The default based on the json you are sending is a `List` of a custom type (with the properties:

```
"productHeight": "",
"productWeight": ""
```

as member variables). Therefore, consider defining a custom type and storing it as a List in your entity.

Otherwise, if you really want to use a map [take a look at this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map#deserialization) to define custom deserializers for that.